# How can I insert elements of one list into another list in the same order?

Tags: python, list, indexing, insert, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list of fruits and i want to insert the elements of that list into another list. Using List comprehension I would have a code that looks like this:

```
fruit = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "peach"]

my_list = []

[my_list.insert(0, i) for i in fruit]

print(my_list)
```

This returns:

```
['peach', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple']
```

However, i want the elements arranged in the same order as the original list.
My idea was just reversing it like this:

```
[my_list.insert(-1, i) for i in fruit]
```

But that returns for whatever reason:

```
['orange', 'banana', 'peach', 'apple']
```

Can somebody explain me why using the index [-1] results in this odd order? How could I achieve the original order?

EDIT:

I forgot to add that I'm looking for a method that inserts the list elements at the beginning of the list, so adding the elements of

```
more_fruit = ["pear", "pineapple", "coconut"]
```

in

```
my_list = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "peach"]
```

should result in

```
my_list = ["pear", "pineapple", "coconut", "apple", "orange", "banana", "peach"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not recommended to use "side effects" within a list comprehension nor to use them in place of a for loop.  You can insert a list into another list using simple subscripts however:

```
more_fruit = ["pear", "pineapple", "coconut"]
my_list    = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "peach"]

my_list[0:0] = more_fruit
```

output:

```
print(my_list)

# ['pear', 'pineapple', 'coconut', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'peach']
```

*note: a subscript is a reference to some elements in the list, either a single element or a range of elements. In this case, we are replacing a range of elements containing zero elements starting at position 0.*

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Can you clarify though what you mean by suscrip? Subscripts? Searching for that shows me something else apparently, I've never seen this before in my short Python career.

Comment: sorry "suscrip" was a horrible typo.

Answer (score 1):

The insertion index is the index that the element will have *after* the insertion. What you are really trying, is:

```
[my_list.insert(len(my_list), i) for i in fruit]
```

Which turns `my_list` into the expected copy. 
Using `-1` as insertion index inserts *before* the last element, which doesn't work for the first one because there is no last element yet to be preceded, hence the weird order.

That being said, you really shouldn't use comperehensions for side effects if you don't use the resulting list. Note that `[my_list.insert(-1, i) for i in fruit]` actually returns `[None, None, None, None]`.

There are better ways to achieve  such a shallow copy:

```
my_list.extend(fruit)
my_list = fruit[:]
my_list = [f for f in fruit]
```

To name just a few.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to add a new item to the end of the list you can use `append` instead of `insert`.
2. The reason you get the "mixed" ordering for your version with `-1` is that inserting into the `-1` position put the element in the "next to the last" element inside your list.

So if you have the list `["a", "b"]` and you insert `"c"` into the position of `-1` - your new list will be `["a", "c", "b"]`.

As for your code - you can use:

```
[my_list.append(x) for x in fruit]
```

Or even better:

```
my_list = fruit[::]
```

Which will copy the items of `fruit` into `my_list`

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much. Unfortunately i forgot to clarify that i need the elements at the beginning at the list, could you look at the updated question? Sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

use list.index() it returns the index of the element , if you know the index of the elements in the original list then you can insert exactly as the original list.

```
fruit = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "peach"]

my_list = []

[my_list.insert(fruit.index(i),i) for i in fruit]

print(my_list)
```

the output is:

the original list Fruit : ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'peach']

and my_list :

```
['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'peach']
```